# Django query content_type by name not content_type_id

Tags: python, sql, django

I need to count some relations from my Flags model to my Post Model. Now I don't understand how to query for the Post model name at my query, I understand how to query for the content_type_id but not for the content_type (as a string). I got something like this on my mind:

```
Q(models.Q(('app_label', 'App'), ('model', 'Post'))
```

but I don't know how the Syntax has to look like at that point, can smb. help?

example:

```
def post_list_most_bad_flags(request):
    p_counter_query = Flags.objects.filter(content_type_id=12) # --> Want to replace this with content_type instead if content_type_id
    counter = p_counter_query.count()
    print(counter)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `Flags` has a `ForeignKey` (or `OneToOneField` to the `ContentType` model, you can filter with:

```
def post_list_most_bad_flags(request):
    p_counter_query = Flags.objects.filter(
        content_type__app_label='App',
        content_type__model='Post'
    )
    counter = p_counter_query.count()
    print(counter)
```